# Group notification react native

Tags: react-native, notifications

I have problem with group notification.
I try create notification on group like whatsapp.
I user react-native-firebase and set:

```
new firebase.notifications.Notification()
.setSound(obj.sound)
.setNotificationId(obj.dataId)
.setTitle(obj.title)
.setBody(obj.body)
.setData(obj.data)
//For Android
.android.setChannelId(obj.channel._channelId)
.android.setLargeIcon(obj.largeIcon) //Create on mimap
.android.setColor(obj.colorBgIcon)
.android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High)
.android.setVibrate(obj.vibrate)
.android.setAutoCancel(true)
.android.setGroup('group')
.android.setGroupSummary(true)
.android.setTag('Mytag')
.android.setGroupAlertBehaviour(firebase.notifications.Android.GroupAlert.Children)
```

But it not working.
Then I try use another library: react-native-push-notification with default channel

```
autoCancel: true,
largeIcon: 'ic_stat_ic_notification',
smallIcon: 'ic_stat_ic_notification',
color: '#00BBCE',
bigText: message || '',
subText: title || '',
vibration: 'high',
importance: 'high',
group: title,
groupSummary: true,
tag: title,
```

But still not working.
Everyone else have solution, please share me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After many time, I know the answer.
I use silent push notification. From service I push notification with only data. In mobile app, when I receive silent notification, I push local notification.